# Django: displaying all fields of all tables, the dumbest view possible

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I've inherited a Django PostGres application with a model containing around 40 tables.

I've redesigned the model from head to toe, and now I'm setting in to re-build the web front end.  I haven't used Django previous to this project - and no HTML for many years - but I'm happy enough with the ORM end of Django.

As a raw default, I just wanted to display all the fields of a class on an individual html page.  Any references (i.e. ForeignKeys, or ManyToOne references) should appear as html links to another html page, which displays *that* class' data.

The application that I've inherited does more or less that, but uses about 50 modules containing hundreds of boiler-plate views, forms, and serializers - absolutely none of which contain anything remotely intelligent in.  The "active" code on each form just sayd '**all**'.

Rather than autogenerate this code (yuk!), is there a quick way of asking Django to display a basic tabular view unless there is a bespoke view for the table?

Comment: It sounds like the [admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) is what you want, but I'd avoid having it be customer facing. It can be pretty clunky when your dataset grows.

Comment: @schillingt - I'm assuming that's a backdoor into the database itself?  I was more looking for like a default view, which I can improve upon...

Comment: Then I think you will need to look into [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/). You'll still need to do some boilerplate work, but I think you could reduce that amount reasonably.

Comment: @schillingt that sounds like what I'm after.  I have just found out that we are using Django *REST*, so I might have been barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: DRF has a lot of the same concepts as generic views in its ViewSets.

Comment: Thanks, @schillingt.  I've now got the full toolset: Django REST communicating with REACT frontend via JSON.  There are a lot of moving parts, and literally kilobytes of boiler-plate code at both ends.  Given 90% of our forms will probably need a simple table of value fields, this seems quite inefficient - are you aware of any tempting alternatives?  I'll look up DRF and generic views, that's for sure...

Comment: That's the route I'd likely go. The other big name these days is GraphQL. For python the package is `graphene` and on the front-end the big player is Apollo.

Comment: Thanks, @schillingt - that's extremely helpful!